# mvc 4 bundling just jquery 1.7 results in "unexpected token '('"

Tags: bundle, asp.net-mvc-4, minify

**_Layout.cshtml**:

```
<script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/desktop-js-bundle")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Global.asax.cs**:

```
var desktopJsBundle = new Bundle("~/desktop-js-bundle", new CssMinify());
desktopJsBundle.AddFile("~/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js");
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(desktopJsBundle);
```

When I view source on `http://localhost:52221/desktop-js-bundle?v=...`, I see the following:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(2,1): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '('
(and some other errors like this)
*/
/*! jQuery v.1.7.1 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */
(function(a,b)(function cy(a)....... (the rest of the jquery library. NOTE: starts with that "(")
```

What am I missing? Does the bundling offered in mvc 4 really not like jquery's way of starting with that "("? Thanks.

**UPDATE!**
I was using `new CssMinify()` instead of `new JsMinify()`.

Comment: Are you trying to `CssMinify` the already minified `jquery-1.7.1.min.js`? Is it has the same result with the unmified `jquery-1.7.1.js`?

Comment: Agreed, no need to minify a file that is already minified.  Just burns additional cpu cycles. It may also be causing the issue.

Comment: I'll be having several files in the bundle eventually, some that are already minified, some that aren't.  I'd like to just minify all of them, vs having one bundle for ~/already-minified and ~/now-minified

Comment: as a note, the unminified jquery also starts w/ a "(", so, I bet I would experience the same issue. http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js may just have to wait on minifying until mvc 4 is officially out and not in beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing it won't like the missing semicolon of the .min jquery. Try passing in the unminified jquery. On another note, I would not have a bundler/minifier include jquery. You will typically get better perf by going directly to the google or MS CDN since these will likely be pre cached on your viewer's browser.

Comment: missing semicolon? and, good pt on using a CDN.  I wonder if the perf boost would outweigh the extra http request that the website would have to make tho. nice to bundle my jquery in with my other js files, because, it trims anything js-related to 1 request, vs. 1 for everything-but-jquery, and another for the jquery.

Comment: Thats just it. Its likely that there will not be an extra request because if the user has the google jquery cached on their browser, it will never make the trip. Re the semicolon: a common problem with bundlers is the failure to concatenate javascript that is not terminated in a semicolon. Minification trims the ending semicolon so if you later try to bundle that script, many bundlers will result in javascript errors.

Comment: great, thanks! maybe mvc 4 full release will have some of these issues ironed out. I'm going to take your advice and NOT include jquery in my bundle, and instead, use http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js (as good as any cdn, right?)

Comment: I'm an idiot. I was doing `new CssMinify()` for my javascript bundle and not `new JsMinify()`. anyways, marking this as answer b/c it's super informative.

Comment: I have been having the same issue. My original understanding was that by convention, if a file already ends in min.js the optimizer would bundle it but not re-minify it. But inspecting the response, apparently not. So, 2 questions: how does one specify to skip minification on a file or a file pattern from a bundle which uses .Include on a whole folder, which may contain both debug and minified scripts? And why (for me) does only Opera (12.0) appear to have a problem parsing the twice minified jQuery? I may end up using a CDN instead, but would like the option not to.